# MapView is causing the app to crash. No errors printed in log. React-Native-Maps

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-maps

It was working fine before, but now my views that contain a mapview crash and only work when I take the mapview out. I have been through several issues on the react-native-maps github page that seemed similar to mine and most say it has to do with google play services that you have added in dependencies in the build.gradle and I have made changes with regard to that however nothing has changed. I checked and my maps api key is just fine and the library is set up according to the guidelines. If you know what the problem might be please comment or answer. The mapviews were working well a few days ago and now, they are not.

**Inside my build.gradle**
*sdk versions...*

```
  compileSdkVersion 23
   buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
```

*Dependancies....*

```
compile(project(':react-native-maps')){
        exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-base'
        exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-maps'
    }
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:+'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:+'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:+'
```

**Inside the manifest**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>

   <meta-data
  android:name="API_KEY"
  android:value="AIzaSyCV3tjuvgsj1HqTdKqtyh-x8oFLmupq9iI"/>
```

**Inside the MainApplications.java**

```
 new MapsPackage(),
Inside settings.gradle
include ':react-native-maps'
project(':react-native-maps').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-maps/lib/android')
```

**How I call MapView**

```
<MapView
      region={{            
        longitude: LONGITUDE,
        latitude: LATITUDE, 
        longitudeDelta: LONGITUDE_DELTA,
        latitudeDelta: LATITUDE_DELTA
      }
      }
      style={styles.container}
    >
```

***Anything that might mean something:*** 
I am using geolocation to get the users location and then switch the initial region to the users current location coordinates.

Comment: Have you given permission to application to access location from settings?

Comment: I don't understand, what do you mean? :) 
A prompt to have the user turn on location? 
Location was on during all of my tests.

Comment: In Mobile  settings -> application -> in permissions -> turn on location

Answer (score 1):

Try this
In constructor

```
this.state= {
      region: {
        latitude: 24.4539,
        longitude: 54.3773 ,
        latitudeDelta: LATITUDE_DELTA,
        longitudeDelta: LONGITUDE_DELTA,
      },
    };
```

this method for changing region

```
onRegionChange(region: Object) {
    this.setState({
      region : region
    });
  }
```

call MapView

```
<MapView style={{flex: 1}}
         initialRegion={this.state.region}
         region={this.state.region}
         onRegionChangeComplete={(region) => this.onRegionChange(region)} />
```